# Required role/permissions to create API Key in Azure ApplicationInsights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, api-key

"Create API key" is greyed out in ApplicationInstance "API Access" page.   What permissions or settings are required to enable "Create API Key" for my account?

Comment: Could my reply solve your issue?

Answer (score 3):

You need to ask the `Owner` of the subscription or application insight to give your account as an RBAC role e.g. `Application Insights Component Contributor`/`Contributor`/`Owner`(from least to most).

Navigate to the subscription or application insight in the portal -> `Access control (IAM)` -> `Add` -> `Add role assignment` -> select your account and add a role like above -> `Save`, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal#grant-access).

For more details about azure RBAC roles, you could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview).

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.)